# Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:

Tags: r

```
train(Species~.,data = df_train,method="rpart",,trcontrol=numfolds,tunegrid=cpgrid)
```

Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:

```
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :3     NA's   :3    
Error: Stopping
In addition: There were 26 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Here is the data set `df_train`

```
head(df_train)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and post your question

Comment: Try starting with `train(Species~., data = df_train, method="rpart", tuneGrid=data.frame(cp=seq(0.001, 0.005, 0.001)))` and be careful about the syntax of `train` (tuneGrid and not tunegrid, trControl and not trcontrol)